# IE does not navigate to default.htm

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis-7

I've created an application and I published it on my server. I would like to set it so when the user navigates to

appName.domainName.com

they would automatically be redirected to

appName.domainName.com/myApplication.aspx

I've set up a Default.htm file in my root directory with a redirection meta tag. However, if I set the page to be my home page, whenever I first open IE, I get a "Interent Explorer cannot display the webpage" message. Once I hit F5 it refreshes and works correctly. Does anyone have a clue as to what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to configure IIS to use myApplication.aspx as the "default page" when navigating to your application instead of redirecting based on a previous default page.

Using the [IIS documentation](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/defaultDocument), you could add this to your web.config

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
         <files>
            <add value="myApplication.aspx" />
         </files>
      </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Or otherwise use the IIS manager to set the value to your page.